# Sorting word frequency in two arrays

Tags: c

How to sort the output array? Displays the frequency of occurrence of a word in a different, disordered order. I would like him to output words in descending order, from larger to smaller. How can I implement this sorting?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        char** words = NULL; 
        int num_words = 0; 
        char* delim = " \t\n,.!?:";
        int size_file = 0; 
        FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        size_file = ftell(fp); 
        printf("%d\n", size_file);
        char* buffer = calloc(size_file + 1, sizeof(char)); //буфер

        if (buffer == NULL) {
            printf("Error\n");
            exit(-1);
        }

        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fread(buffer, 1, size_file, fp);
        printf("\nText file\n\n");

        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        char* istr = strtok(buffer, delim);
        while (istr) {
            words = realloc(words, (num_words + 1) * sizeof(char*));
            words[num_words++] = istr;
            istr = strtok(NULL, delim);
            //printf("%s\n", istr);
        }

        /*for (int i=0; i<num_words;i++) {
      printf("%p\n", words[i]);
      }*/
        printf("Number of characters in file :%d\n", size_file);
        printf("Number of words in file :%d\n\n", num_words);
        for (int i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
            puts(words[i]);
        }

        int* wcnt = calloc(num_words, sizeof(int));
        char* is_first = calloc(num_words, sizeof(char));
        for (int i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
            wcnt[i]++;
            for (int j = 0; j < num_words; j++) {
                if (i != j && strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0) {
                    if (wcnt[i]++ == 1 && i < j)
                        is_first[i] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
            if (wcnt[i] == 1 || is_first[i])
                if (wcnt[i] > 1 ) {
                    printf("%s = %d\n", words[i], wcnt[i]);
                }
        }
      fclose(fp);
      free(buffer);
      free(words);
      free(wcnt);
      free(is_first);
      return 0;
    }
```

How to sort the output array? Displays the frequency of occurrence of a word in a different, disordered order. I would like him to output words in descending order, from larger to smaller. How can I implement this sorting? for instance
"the"=4;
"was"=3;
....

Comment: Avoid incrementing the reallocated array size by one each time.  Double the amount of memory you use each time.  That requires two counters, one for the number of words read and another for the number of words allocated.

Comment: And why is it better to double and not increase? And how do I still sort in descending order?

Comment: If the array needs to move, you end up with quadratic behaviour as the previous versions of the array are copied to the new location.  Look up 'Schlemiel the Painter' (or 'Shlemiel the Painter' — both work).